# Различные языки в сообщении, что вопрос перенесён

Tags: дефект, локализация

Не знаю, сюда ли писать или на Мету англоязычного SO. [Перенесённый на английский Stack Overflow вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37183413/5951529). Сообщение:

[image: Перенесённый с русскоязычного Stack Overflow вопрос]

`программистов` → `programmers`

Comment: Это значит, что нужно все описания сайтов будет локализировать на все используемые языки. Хм.

Comment: Спасибо! Отличный дефект! Будет повод починить «for программистов» и все рядом стоящее.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, так вроде уже было что-то про QA for программистов

Comment: См. также: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2901/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA

Comment: На сколько помню, там было про stackexchange.com, который не переведен вообще.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, вот прям в [ответе](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/980/186999)

Comment: @Grundy, ага, спасибо! Буду трясти ответственных с удвоенной силой.